# Accessing text box from other thread

Tags: c#, textbox

I am writing text to text box from another thread using code as below

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
private void SetText1(string text)
    {
        if (this.textBox7.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText1);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text});
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox7.Text = text;
        }
}
```

Now I have to write text to multiple text boxes (eg textBox8, 9, 10). I wanted this same function **SetText1** to work. SO is there a way that I can make textBox7 variable in this function and use the textbox I intend to write from the other thread.

Otherwise if I follow my current approach, then if I want to write to ten textboxes I will need ten **SetText functions**

Comment: Why not pass the `TextBox` to the delegate?

Comment: I don't get it. What does `this.Invoke` is doing here? `Invoke` is `Control` method. Usually controls are referenced by background threads as thread creation parameters, and then Invoke is called on controls. Now, if you have control in your thread and you call Invoke on it you already know what control you addressing your call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(TextBox textBox, string text);
private void SetText(TextBox textBox, string text)
{
    if (textBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] {textBox, text});
    }
    else
    {
        textBox.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

you can do it just with one function - you don't even need the delegate

```
 private void SetText(TextBox txt, string text)
    {
        if (txt.InvokeRequired)
        {
           Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => txt.Text = text));
        }
        else
        {
            txt.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which namespace Invoke() method are we talking here? In 2019 it doesn't automatically recognize the reference and doesn't offer any suggestions on namespace. Searching isn't showing anything that looks like an exact match. I'm trying to write to a RichTextBox from within a ProgressChangedEventHandler.

Comment: this.Invoke - so the form (though the definition is actually a few base classes up in Control)